# How to server all request of one client from the same web server in case of f5 load balancer to track session?

Tags: java, tomcat, webserver, load-balancing, f5

I have f5 load balancer and 2 web servers, If client/user A's First request served by web server 1 then client/user A's second request should also be served by web server 1 only. What is the best way to achieve thisÀ?

Purpose of doing this is to maintain session to that specific client/user in specific server.

Comment: You're looking for session stickiness (or session affinity).

Comment: Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Thanks Kayaman I am looking for Session Stickiness

Comment: Thanks Thakookooguy, it helps me

Answer (score 0):

Sticky Sessions with f5 should be the solution; f5 "Sticky Sessions" sticks with persistence session, load balancer decides that every recurring calls like postback or new page request of an identified user should redirect to that same server.

For details please click **[here](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/lc_9_x/manuals/product/lc_config_guide_10_1/lc_persist_profiles.html)**.

Comment: Thanks Sudipta Maiti, I will use sticky sessions